# Strange bug in Julia or Screen

Tags: linux, julia, gnu-screen

On Debian 8 Linux, I use vim together with screen to send lines from vim to a julia session. Today, I tried https://github.com/Keno/Cxx.jl. I followed the instructions there (i.e. I compiled the latest version 0.5.0-dev+3609 of Julia). The following bug appeared when I tried example 1, I could pinpoint it to the following simple steps:

1. Create the following files (don't overwrite your own files):

   `printf "using Cxx\ncxx\"\"\"#include<iostream> \"\"\"\ncxx\"\"\"void testfunction(){std::cout<<\"worked\"<< std::endl;}\"\"\"\njulia_function() = @cxx testfunction()\n" > start`

   and `printf "julia_function()\n" > freeze`
2. Open terminal 1 (I use gnome-terminal) and write `screen -S session` and then start Julia with `julia`. It should look like

```
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  A fresh approach to technical computing
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |  Documentation: http://docs.julialang.org
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?help" for help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 0.5.0-dev+3609 (2016-04-18 07:07 UTC)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Commit a136a6e (0 days old master)
|__/                   |  x86_64-linux-gnu

julia>
```

3. Open terminal 2 and do

   ```
   screen -S session -p 0 -X eval "readreg p start" "paste p"
   ```

   Terminal 1 should now look like

```
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  A fresh approach to technical computing
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |  Documentation: http://docs.julialang.org
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?help" for help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 0.5.0-dev+3609 (2016-04-18 07:07 UTC)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Commit a136a6e (0 days old master)
|__/                   |  x86_64-linux-gnu

julia> using Cxx

julia> cxx"""#include<iostream> """
true

julia> cxx"""void testfunction(){std::cout<<"worked"<< std::endl;}"""
true

julia> julia_function() = @cxx testfunction()
julia_function (generic function with 1 method)

julia>
```

Now the strange bug appears: writing "ju", using TAB to complete to "julia_function" and adding "()" by hand in terminal 1 leads to

```
julia> julia_function()
worked

julia>
```

But if I do steps 1, 2, 3 and then `screen -S session -p 0 -X eval "readreg p freeze" "paste p"` in terminal 2 or write `julia_function()` in terminal 1 without using TAB to complete then I get a freeze in terminal 1:

```
julia> julia_function()
```

If I do steps 1, 2, 3, use TAB completion as described above, then (i.e. *after* the first call, which compiles the function) `screen -S session -p 0 -X eval "readreg p freeze" "paste p"` in terminal 2 and `julia_function()` without using TAB in terminal 1 work as expected (it prints "worked") and don't cause a freeze.

If I do not use screen at all, it works (with and without TAB). Can you please tell me what is going on here?